# Moquette MQTT server more than 1024 connections

Tags: mqtt

Anyone know what the configurations are which allow moquette to service
more than 1024 connections? None of the files in config/ seem to help.
Even though our "open file" limit is much higher for the Java process:

```bash
> grep "open files" /proc/10662/limits
Max open files            500000               500000               files
```

the server does not want to handle more than 1024 connections.

Comment: It might be useful to show what error you get when you try and connect the 1025th client.